# Linq query to compare List<DateTime> within a IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, date, datetime

I have a Class with property that returns list of Dates

```
public class DummyClass
{
        public IEnumerable<DateTime> ListOfDates
        {
            get
            {
               return someListOfDateTimes();
            }
        }
}
```

Now I need to compare each date inside this class with my start and end date to get only those records that ave any date within start and end date.

If my ListOfDates property use to return only one date then following would have worked but how to compare list of dates

```
dummyClassItems.Where(x => x.ListOfDates > startTime && x.ListOfDates < endTime);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you want to check each item's `List<DateTime>` for `startTime` and `endTime`, you can do that like:

```
var query = dummyClassItems.Where(x => 
                x.ListOfDates.Any(r=>  r > startTime && r < endTime));
```